# Not sure how to set up my dns and heroku apps to do what I want

Tags: heroku, dns, nameservers

Heroku offers US and EU servers and I want my users to connect to the server which is closer to them, so if someone connects from the EU, I will redirect them to the EU server and the same for the US.

My idea was to have them connect to main domain name, example.com that would connect to the US server, which would check where the users are coming from, and then redirect them to where I want them to be, and all this while they are looking at the same domain "example.com". Heroku wont let me add the same domain twice, and I don't know where I should configure what for the DNS. My domain provider has a nameserver section and I'm not sure what to add there. Basically I want all the request and server load to go onto the Heroku page, and not onto the default DNS server which only redirects or loads the Heroku page inside a frame.

They way it seems correct, is to connect to example.com, which is the US Heroku page and then redirect inside a frame or something to the EU page... not sure if this is the best way, and like I mentioned, I'm not sure how to setup the namespace and stuff so they connect directly to the Heroku server instead of the default domain server.

Could someone explain to me what I need to do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to run a multi-region application on Heroku and I'd caution against trying to work your way around this limitation. Some areas that cause users problems when trying to attempt this are:

- You can't have the same [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) on two apps (as you've already identified).
- There is no way to setup a multi-master database configuration so each app has a db in its own region. Likewise, maintaining a single master for both apps results in very high latency for one of the apps.
- The connection overhead of any other trickery, like what you propose here, often negates any latency improvement the user sees from accessing the app in their closest region.
- Using a CDN for static assets, and having a proper [http cache header](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers) strategy often gets you 90% of the way to the performance of a truly geo-distributed app.

To drill further into your question, I'm not sure what you mean here?

> how to setup the namespace and stuff so they connect directly to the Heroku server instead of the default domain server

Hope that helps!